# Angular 2 loadChildren not working with canActivateChild

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I'm trying to use Angular2 to lazy load some modules. I could make it work, but when I use it with canActivateChild, it blocks the navigation but load the module, I don't know if I need to do anything else, but I'd like to load the module only if I'm enable to access the route. For example, this is an admin dashboard and I want to load the AdminModule only when the user is logged.

This is my main module routing:

```
export const routing = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {
        path: '',
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'adm', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];
```

And this is my admin routing:

```
export const adminRouting = [
    { path: '',
        children: [
            { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent },
            { path: 'support', component: SupportComponent },
            // more routes
        ]
    },
];
```

Like I said, everything in the navigation is working as expect, but when I'm not logged I wanted to prevent the lazyLoad module to be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the routing guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules) on angular I believe you have to use `canLoad` instead of `canActivate`.